# Auto Incrementing data in a column as each day passes

Tags: mysql, datetime

In my database, a table has a column with an integer that needs to increment every day, counting the days that have passed from a date.
Is there any way I can do this?
I know Auto Increment exists, but I don't know if it fits for this occasion. 
I found a solution using mysql events, but now I'm having trouble with the syntax.
PHPMyadmin gives me a form to complete.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZSVg.jpg

I'm having trouble because I don't know what informations to put into it.

Comment: 'integer that needs to increment every day' - from what date and do all entries for that day have the same number?

Comment: Please add table definition and a sample of what you what it to look like.

Comment: This sounds like a bad database design. You can easily calculate the day difference between two dates in any sql statement.

Comment: So you are saying that it's easier to calculate the difference in a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to compute the elapsed days in a query, not to update the table every day.

For example, suppose you have a table with columns `id` and `start_date`.

This query gives you the elapsed days.

```
SELECT id, 
       DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), start_date) elapsed
  FROM tbl
```

Doing it this way is better than changing the table every day, for several reasons.

1. It always works even if the event doesn't fire for some reason.
2. Updating an entire table can get more and more expensive as the table grows.
3. The computational cost of computing the elapsed days is **far less** than the computational cost of updating every day.
4. If you happen to use incremental backups, updating the whole table defeats that.
5. It's a good practice to avoid representing the same information multiple times in the database.

You can also add a [generated (virtual) column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) to the table or use a VIEW.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at event schedulers in MySQL, you could use them to run a job that increments your values once a day.

[MySQL Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html)

Comment: It seems that working with this solution should work. I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

The following example creates a recurring event that updates a row in a table.

First, create a new table named counter.

```sql
CREATE TABLE counter (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    counts VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

Second, create an event using the  CREATE EVENT statement:

```sql
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS count_event
ON SCHEDULE AT EVERY interval STARTS timestamp [+INTERVAL] ENDS timestamp [+INTERVAL]
DO
  UPDATE counter SET counts = counts + YOUR_COUNT WHERE id = YOUR_ID;
```

Replace interval timestamps, your_count and your_id with real variables